# XAML Command Inside a Style

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

UWP I'm trying to set a Command on a Button Style, but my Command doesn't fire :(

Anything obvious come to mind ?

```
<Style x:Key="TimeBtnStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ClickBtnStyle}" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=vm.CommandTester}"/>
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Content}"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent">
                    <Border CornerRadius="12" Background="White" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="4">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}">
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Binding is not supported in Setter. Even if it does, don't do it.

Comment: @JustinXL So how do I call a Command from a Style ?

Comment: I don't recommend doing this. Why do you need a command in a style anyway?

Comment: @JustinXL Because I have multiple buttons all with same Style and Command.  I assumed that putting the Command in a Style was the way to go ?

Comment: Additionally the Command's Parameter is bound to each Button's Content.

Comment: I'd put it inside a `UserControl`.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the button in a ContentTemplate of a ContentControl.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
  <Button Command="{Binding ICommand}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
```